# Stopping a running application in Eclipse from the keyboard?

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I can run an application with ⌘F11 or ⇧⌘F11, but how do I stop it from the keyboard?

Comment: I'm having this problem too. My source code is being executed, but the items in the Run menu are all grayed out and none of them is clickable nor their shortcuts are working. I can click the red terminate button in the toolbar with the mouse and that terminates. I'm very much interested in a keyboard shortcut. I guess it has to do with the menu items all being grayed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer from Austin in this question: [What is the short cut in eclipse to terminate debugging/running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321118/what-is-the-short-cut-in-eclipse-to-terminate-debugging-running)

The accepted answer in that question only works if you're debugging.

UPDATE:

I checked on this, and at first I couldn't get it to work. It turns out that if you want the terminate command to be available in the Java Editor perspective, you have to go to Window ->
Customize Perspective -> Commands and add the Debug command group to the perspective.

Then, go to Window -> Preferences -> Keys, find the Terminate binding, and change "When" to "In Windows".

That worked for me - I was able to start the app with F11 and terminate with CTRL-F2.

Comment: Thanks! I had to go to the Debug perspective and then back to the Java perspective for it to start working.

Answer (score 0):

The Terminate command is mapped to ⌘F2 in my workspace.