# Java 1.7.0_03 Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I just upgraded to the latest Java

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
> javac -version
javac 1.7.0_03
```

I am having issues to execute Java program from the command-line. For instance:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in main");
    }
}
```

I compiled it on the command-line, then try to execute it:

```
> javac Tester.java
> java Tester
Error: Could not find or load main class Tester
```

Is this a bug?
Strangely, I have no problem to execute the program using Eclipse.

Comment: Is the `Tester` class in the default package? And is the file `Tester.class` in the current directory after compiling?

Comment: @Inerdial, the _Tester_ class is exactly as shown here, with no package reference. and yes, the _Tester.class_ file resides in the same directory of executing the compilation and the _java_ iteself.

Comment: Had to test, exact same program works for me with same version. Only thing I can think of checking is that the classpath includes `.`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Indeed. And the conclusion is -- do not code late in night. THANKS! any clue how do I mark this thread as closed\solved?

Comment: I think you should be able to mark the answer from @gsteff below as a solution, the comments up here can't be marked as that :)

Comment: This is why you should never ever set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, certainly not globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your CLASSPATH environment variable set?  When I do

```
export CLASSPATH=/tmp
java Tester
```

I get a NoClassDefFoundError, though not the exact same error message you quoted.

Comment: the ``classpath`` has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: I on the other hand get the exact same error message with the same Java version on Windows when I don't have `.` in the classpath.

Comment: @MrRoth: It does. If you have set `CLASSPATH` and it does not include `.` or another reference that indirectly includes `.`, you will get that exact error. Try `set CLASSPATH=` in a console window and if it works then, that was your problem. (I know you use Windows since the build number is different on Linux/Solaris)

Comment: @mihi, thanks! how do I mark this thread as closed? can you help me with different thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340538/eclipse-terminate-shotcut

Comment: the solution is with _mihi_ :) just add the current working directory to the classpath

Answer (score 2):

Run jar files in console mode.
java -jar filename.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to run Tomcat and realized it was because I was using a 64 bit version of Tomcat on a 32 bit system. Once I tried the 32 bit version, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run program in current working directory where your class reside.

java gives three options.

first option

java -cp  Tester

Second option for current working directory

java -cp . Tester

Third option export CLASSPATH variable

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:.
(this is the best one if your directory changes)
or

export CLASSPATH=$PWD

or

export CLASSPATH=

after that you must sorce the bashrc or bashprofile.

Answer (score 0):

just set your classpath in system variables:

```
classpath=.
```