# short cut key for java debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any short-key to terminate all active debug launches, remove all terminated launches from debug view and to show debug history quick menu?

I found short key to terminate single launch from here
[What is the short cut in eclipse to terminate debugging/running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321118/what-is-the-short-cut-in-eclipse-to-terminate-debugging-running/14831622#14831622)

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321118/what-is-the-short-cut-in-eclipse-to-terminate-debugging-running)

Comment: No, I don't think such a key binding exists.