# Where is the "Terminate all" button in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I can't seem to find (even in **debug mode**) the following icon in eclipse: [image: Terminate All button]
. Is there a way to make it visible again (I suspect that I need to check some box in Window->Preferences but I can't find it...)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Switch to the Debug view.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831744/short-cut-key-for-java-debugging

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I was not able to solve my issue with the propossed solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831744/short-cut-key-for-java-debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the terminate all button is **not available in Kepler**. Hence, the best way I've found to terminate all current runs is (workaround):

- Open the Debug tab.
- Select all runs (Ctrl+A)
- Right click on selection and select option "Terminate/Disconnect All"

Here is a screenshot exposing this workaround:

[image: How to "Terminate All" runs]

It is not as simple as using the button. Nevertheless this solution is good enough for my needs.

Kudos to @Velthune for pointing out that *"In versions [Luna, Kepler, Juno, Indigo, Helios ] I can't find that icon!"*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in perspective Debug view.

- **solution A**

  take a look at [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-terminateall.htm).
- **solution B**

  Search in:

  ```
  Window -> Customize Perspective -> Tool Bar Visibility (or Menu Visibility)
  ```

  to check if your icon is visible.
- **Plus**

  You can create a customize shorcut to "Terminate All":

  ```
  Window -> Customize Perspective -> Commands.
  ```

  Here select 'Debug' group and modify your shortcut.

Comment: I am using Kepler. If what you say is right, then how am I supposed to terminate all runs? After developping for a few hours, I find out that my Eclipse is slower and slower. Am I supposed to: terminate every run individually, restart the program or else?

Comment: links I've provided was for c++, but you're using java. My mistake. http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-terminateall.htm here there is your icon too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no coolbar action to `Terminate All`. That action is available in the `Debug View`.

When apps are running, right-click in the `Debug View`, and there you have it.

To extend Eclipse and add it yourself in the coolbar, you can make a plugin and add that.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the **Debug**(perspective) tab on the **Upper Right Corner** of eclipse,then select **Reset** option. After that your Debug perspective will come back to usual. And then you terminate all your Debug process/thread.