# How to terminate currently running eclipse application via keyboard?

Tags: styledtext

I am new to eclipse.Please suggest a keyboard shortcut to terminate currently running eclipse application

Comment: alt-F4 under windows for a gui application

Comment: Apparently Ctrl+F2 by default for the "Terminate" action which should work for console apps

Comment: I tried with cntrl+F2 but no use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the short cut in eclipse to terminate debugging/running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321118/what-is-the-short-cut-in-eclipse-to-terminate-debugging-running)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to 
`Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys`
and set the `Exit` command to whatever suits you.